# Why does this jquery dropdown not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code seems to show everything correctly but then when launched in the browser, the drop down doesn't work. The hover styling and everything works correctly except for the dropdown.
Thank you.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GS4 Concept Home Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="unicss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Main Cat 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Cat 2 </a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-5</a></li>
            </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main Cat 3 </a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-7</a></li>
            </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    background-image:url(Images/backgroundmain.jpg);
    min-width:100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
}

#header{
    background-color:#474747;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#container{
    margin:auto;
    width:70%;
}

.navigation {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.navigation li {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.navigation li a {
    background:#262626;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding:8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:1px solid #F2861D;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    color:#F2861D;
}

.navigation ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:3px solid #F2861D;
}

.navigation ul li {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border-top:none;
}

.navigation ul a {
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    padding:8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #6B6B6B;
}

.navigation ul a:hover {
    color:#F2861D;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navigation li').hover(

    function() {
        $('ul', this).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $('ul', this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scripts are in the wrong order.

Instead of

```
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Script/main.js"></script>
```

And also make a nested list, so that your selectors are correct in the main.js file:

```
<ul class="navigation">
   <li><a href="#">Main Cat 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Main Cat 2 </a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2-5</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Main Cat 3 </a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 3-7</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This make a difference. The problem is, that you've got a second mistake in your html. I've added the solution in my answer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the selectors work on this list from the jquery..? I can't seem to understand it, as well as why the sub categories must be contained in the ul of the main they are meant for.

Comment: You're searching for a `ul` element in the context of your current `li` element. `$('ul', this)` is the same as `$(this).find('ul')`. So if there is no `ul` element in your list item, you can't find one. This is the reason why you have to nest the whole list in the list item.

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can get problems when you use "#" as the href value.